# Unable to change variable while transversing for loop

Tags: regex, scala

I'm building a simple program and have seem to have ran into an odd issue that to me, doesn't make sense. The program takes a text file and parses it line by line. It then does one of the three actions based upon the characteristics of that line:

If the line has content, copy it to a variable declared outside the for loop
If the line starts with a specific delimiting character, append the active line to the variable declared outside the for loop
IF the line is blank, add it to a Set that I've created, and set the variable to blank.

However, it's not appending the strings when the second condition occurs. Upon debugging, it looks like the if condition triggers, but nothing within that block seems to execute. Attempts to remove unneeded characters (all strings that triggers this condition in debug mode show as \t--, and appending these to the current string being built seem to be ignored. Here's the code I'm using to attempt to illustrate a bit better.

```
var activeTextLine:String = "";

    for(line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()) {
      if (line.isEmpty() == false) {
        if (line.startsWith("\t") == true) {
          var temp:String = line;
          temp.replace("\t--", "");
          activeTextLine.concat(temp);
        } else {
          activeTextLine = line.stripLineEnd;
        }
      }  

      if (line.isEmpty() == true) {
        textLinesSet.add(activeTextLine);
        activeTextLine = "";
      }
    }
```

Attempts using filter and regex also have proven fruitless for parsing out the unneeded characters, nor as using the + operator for concating strings. I'm almost thinking that line that's storing the active line is immutable and hence I can't modify its contents at all, but haven't been able to find anything that says one way or another.

So long story short, I know I'm doing something wrong....i'm just at a loss as to what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String`s are immutable. You should do something like:

```
temp = temp.replace("\t--", "");
activeTextLine = activeTextLine.concat(temp);
```

in order to actually modify the strings in `activeTextLine` and `temp`. If you don't want to use `var` for storing your modifiable strings, use a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead.